# Typescript Function Overloading: inaccessible 'this' type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to assign a property to a class instance where the property's signature is a function that's passed `this` as a type.

```
function create<R>(returnValue: R) {
  function wrap(d?: string): R | string {
    if (d) return d
    return returnValue
  }
  return wrap
}

class A {
  prop = create(this)
}
```

It works so long as the function returned from `create` isn't overloaded.

```
function create<R>(returnValue: R) {
  // if no argument, return returnValue
  // otherwise return the argument
  function wrap(d: string): string
  function wrap(): R
  function wrap(d?: string): R | string {
    if (d) return d
    return returnValue
  }
  return wrap
}
```

As soon as I overload the returned function to refine the return type based on passed in arguments, TypeScript complains with:

```
The inferred type of 'prop' references an inaccessible 'this' type. A type annotation is necessary.
```

I'd be happy to add a type annotation, but every signature I've tried has exactly the same problem.

Hardcoding the `this` value to the class `A` won't work because I also want to be able to support subclassing.

I'm not sure how to work around this. Happy to add ugly hacks in the class so long as the resulting types are correct.

```js
function create<R>(returnValue: R) {
  // if no argument, return returnValue
  // otherwise return the argument
  function wrap(d: string): string
  function wrap(): R
  function wrap(d?: string): R | string {
    if (d) return d
    return returnValue
  }
  return wrap
}

class A {
  // Currently gives the error:
  // The inferred type of 'prop' references an inaccessible 'this' type. A type annotation is necessary.
  // If we remove the overloading from the wrap function above, this part works,
  // but it breaks the chaining interface because it doesn't know if the result of new A().prop()
  prop = create(this)
}

class B extends A {
  isB = true // something to differentiate (prevents hardcoding A as return type)
}

const a: A = new A().prop()
const b: B = new B().prop()
b.prop('something')
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQHgEoB8AFOlCCmAGoYA2IaAXIngJSIDeAsAFCKID0-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-TU+m8zlFghz+imD3k5G63eIQ-uOiM9+QWsIcHBMZIQQrHggA)

Would also appreciate any explanation as to why this doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Ahh I think I've found a solution: return `this` and move the `this` type parameter out of the function creator and into the function signature:

```
function create() {
  // if no argument, return this
  // otherwise return the argument
  function wrap<R>(d: string): string
  function wrap<R>(): R
  function wrap<R>(this: R, d?: string): R | string {
    if (d) return d
    return this
  }
  return wrap
}

class A {
  // Currently gives the error:
  // The inferred type of 'prop' references an inaccessible 'this' type. A type annotation is necessary.
  // If we remove the overloading from the wrap function above, this part works,
  // but it breaks the chaining interface because it doesn't know if the result of new A().prop()
  prop = create()
}

class B extends A {
  isB = true // something to differentiate (prevents hardcoding A as return type)
}

const a: A = new A().prop()
const b: B = new B().prop()
b.prop('something')
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQCgJSIDeAsAFCKID0liMwiYciGKA5iALZphQA0i6KCBRIoACxgBnMhWqI44tCgDuUtALRCRiRczaduUGYlCRYCRMpQYADgB4ASgD4cAEwBciSVBQwwrPE9vX39jU2h4JCtbRxdAxAcw8AiLaPtnHHEpTwd+VwB+IJ8-AJzEAB8vYv8iYwo6RDcCQWEkVzqNLVEJaXJEAF9jFu00skHSMggAGwxJSUQAQVq+uQBhYXQeKYBPRFYYADc0ed0lFDgUd2M5ABUxdT9gM7RXHW2bdTh6AHIbc5tvhonpsIMdmEg-BgIKC5jAAEZTdTfLKSQFQd5oAB0izeH3BjCgWEitHmYDQMMkLG2mOuNAAkvRlOp0Bw4EcdPd5EcUFM4BhXCUTOcOBz1GkTMlzEgMHC2Wh+CjEDYWFBLBcANaSXi0xBwkCqmCquHoDCa0XIMQYPyCvzYFDAKHqOHkjAgSQPVWuODHMDIxDqxjKWj0XToSQgKaqr4MNBBhb4TF-OA2fDGJM2RAAXmQJuwqdI40mMzmiAAQog0AAPbBgVzzJYkPpScvZnwgdRySRwLhZGpQJgC4DAwwwLDqHB-NBHHjzS0oVwQOACmpLWadVq4tB4MZkSYIbzMTxLbNkuMJ9P5xdgA9wzwtmNB0vn-75uGJl-fLs9iT+b7biakEAA)

I found this by [simplifying the problem further](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQMpRMYAeANQD4AKASkQG8BYAKEUVElgUQGdtc8AVUgEwBciAmSEE6DJtHhIOOfLxJQAFjDZDuoxNwmNw01nK6KVajQBpEfAPxiKNeg0QxgiEn3uIATuhBekfIgAvroMPtj+iKZsuiGO4X6ynMB0cXQQADYAhmxsiACCVLp8cFjyiAC8KOhlXBxeMGDIpGSpdOkIHIhZlYhgqADuBeQdYF0ARr1ZAHQltcAjtBCdUIgQQvWNyFOzpckkAORQqBwHZEA)

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to reason about the type of `prop` in A where you're defining it, because the function `create` is running synchronously in A's constructor regardless of whether the `this` will eventually be an A instance or a subtype of A. Does the type of `prop` refer to A, because that is where it is being run, or does it refer to the type of the instance on which `prop` is invoked regardless of whether that's A or any subclass of A?

The original pull request for a polymorphic `this` ([microsoft/TypeScript#4910](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4910), [ahejlsberg](https://github.com/ahejlsberg), September 2015) describes it in the initial pull request post:

> The `this` type is a subtype of and assignable to the instance type of
> the containing class or interface, but not vice-versa (because `this`
> might actually be a subclass). That is a breaking change, and certain
> code patterns that previously compiled may now need an extra type
> annotation:
>
> ```
> class A {
>     getInstance() {  // Should be getInstance(): A
>         return this;
>     }
> }
>
> class B extends A {
>     getInstance() {
>         return new B();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The example above now errors because the inferred return type of
> `getInstance` in `A` is `this` and the inferred type of `getInstance` in `B` is
> `B`, which is not assignable to `this`. The fix is to add a return type
> annotation for `getInstance` in `A`.

[Your self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69035627/1426891) neatly disambiguates this case by using an explicit `this` type in the wrapped function, which describes your intent better and avoids the error.